# Grouping JUnit tests with Gradle

Tags: gradle, junit

I created a new Groovy project of integration tests and want to be able to be able to group tests together for different components. For example, some tests are only valid for a docker image, while others are for testing a webapp running locally. I'd also like to get reports for the results of the tests and also be able to run the tests over and over if needed.

Answer (score 3):

The first step to grouping tests in JUnit is to create an interface to name the group. Create this in a package your test classes can reach.

If your Test Class looks like this:

```
package com.example.test.api.get.cert

class ByIssuedBeforeTest {
  //awesome tests
}
```

Then create an empty interface like this:

```
package com.example.test

interface DockerTest {}
```

Now change your Test Class to look like this:

```
package com.example.test.api.get.cert

import org.junit.experimental.categories.Category

@Category(DockerTest.class)
class ByIssuedBeforeTest {
  //awesome tests
}
```

You can also annotate individual tests instead of the whole class.

Now in your build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["src/main/java", "src/main/groovy"]
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["src/test/java", "src/test/groovy"]
        }
    }
}

test {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    reports {
        junitXml.enabled=true
        html.enabled=true
    }
}

task nondockerTest(type: Test) {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    useJUnit {
        excludeCategories 'com.example.test.DockerTest'
    }
}

task dockerTest(type: Test) {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    useJUnit {
        includeCategories 'com.example.test.DockerTest'
    }
}
```

The java plugin for gradle gives you the test task. In the test task we add the `outputs` line in order to keep the test task from ever being labeled as "UP-TO-DATE", in essence forcing gradle to always run the task when we call it instead of caching the result.

The report block enables JUnit report files to be created. They will be placed in the build/reports/tests directory. If you ran the nonDockerTest it would be build/reports/tests/nondockerTest/index.html.

The useJUnit block tells Gradle to use JUnit to run the tests as well as which category of tests to run (if using includeCategories) or category to not run (if using excludeCategories).

`gradle test` to run all the test.

`gradle nondockerTest` to run the tests not labeled as with the DockerTest category.

`gradle dockerTest` to run just tests labeled with the DockerTest category.

Each of these tasks will create reports in the `/build/reports/tests` directory.

Comment: I think this solution would get complicated quickly if different categories of tests have different compilation arguments or dependencies. In this case, I would go for source sets, which have the same effect as creating the JUnit categories with the advantage of defining the build differently for each source set.

Comment: I'll have to look into sourcesets as an alternative. I thought those were only for source vs test folders. I didn't know it could be used to further separate tests from each other.